# about left outer join sql

Tags: sql

So here's the scenario, I have two tables say `payment` and `receipt` with fields

- `payment_date, payment_amount, payment_party_code`

and similarly

- `receipt_date, receipt_amount, receipt_party_code.`

I have 4 rows in payment table, and 11 rows in receipt table.

What I want to do is select all rows from `payment` as well as from `receipt` table where the `party_code` is same. I did by using left outer join but failed because it is doing cartesian product of data.

Please help me out with this

Thanks

Comment: It often makes sense to post your exact code, even if you know it's faulty. The thing is, you might get an answer with a correct solution constructed very similarly to your own so as to highlight the exact difference and, by that means, possibly make it clearer to you what was your mistake. It may not be of importance now, but you might want to keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you want ONLY the records that match on the payment_party_code, you should use an "INNER JOIN".  But as marc_s said, you need to make sure that you specify your join criteria in your "ON" clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and define a JOIN condition on it:

```
SELECT 
  p.payment_date, p.payment_amount, p.payment_party_code,
  r.receipt_date, r.receipt_amount, r.receipt_party_code
FROM
  dbo.Payment p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.Receipt r ON p.payment_party_code = r.receipt_party_code
```

This is for SQL Server (T-SQL). If you leave out the JOIN condition (the `ON p.payment_party_code = r.receipt_party_code` part), you'll get a cartesian product.

This will list all rows from the `Payment` table, and if they have info in the `Receipt` table, that'll be displayed as well.

If you want the opposite (everything from `Receipt`, even if there's no corresponding row in `Payment` for it), you need to either switch around the tables in the `FROM ... LEFT OUTER JOIN` (select from `Receipt` first), or you need to use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` so that you'll get everything from `Receipt`.

You might want to look at the [Venn diagrams of SQL JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) posted by Jeff Atwood - makes it quite clear what the different JOIN types really do...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from party p
left outer join receipt r on p.party_code = r.party_code
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

[Left Outer Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178429%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

The Left Outer Join logical operator returns each row that satisfies the join of the first (top) input with the second (bottom) input. It also returns any rows from the first input that had no matching rows in the second input. The nonmatching rows in the second input are returned as null values. If no join predicate exists in the Argument column, each row is a matching row

```
SELECT 
  pay.payment_date, pay.payment_amount, pay.payment_party_code,
  rec.receipt_date, rec.receipt_amount, rec.receipt_party_code
FROM
  payment pay
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  receipt rec ON pay.payment_party_code = rec.receipt_party_code
```